# How to exclude one branch in Azure DevOps build pipeline

Tags: azure, triggers, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

In Azure DevOps its possible to define [build pipelines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=vsts&tabs=yaml) which by default is executed when a code is pushed to a branch.

I want the pipeline to run for all branches except one. The configuration

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - branchToInclude
    exclude:
    - branchToExclude
```

works when I push to branchToInclude.

But if I take away the include part the pipeline is not executed when I push to branchToInclude.

```
trigger:
  branches:
    exclude:
    - branchToExclude
```

A * instead of branchToInclude is not accepted when I try to save the file. Is there a way to configure a pipeline to execute for all branches except one?

Comment: What do you mean "pipeline is not executed", when you push code from any branch  (not the exclude) the build not get running?

Comment: Yes, I changed the text to make it clearer

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose something like this should work

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - '*'
    exclude:
    - branchToExclude
```

Comment: This exactly what he wrote `A * instead of branchToInclude is not accepted when I try to save the file`

Comment: Ok, you are right, I was a bit hasty, I've just done a test and your answer works, the syntax `"*"` also works.

Comment: Thanks, it works, Azure DevOps shows syntax error on both `'*'` and `"*"` but accepts it in the end.